# Drupal 7 to change the IMCE File Upload Path (Destination)?

Tags: drupal

How can i change the file save-path for IMCE?

Answer (score 1):

The save-path is determined by the IMCE profile that the logged in user is using.  You can configure the profiles in the Configuration of your Drupal site at `admin/config/media/imce`.

When you edit a Profile, the save-paths are set in the section labelled Directories.